# How many edges in a forest with $200$ nodes and $100$ connected components?

Tags: graph-theory

> If $G$ is a forest (in other words, an undirected graph with no circle paths) with $200$ nodes and $100$ connected components, what's the number of edges?

---

**What I tried:**

I drew some examples with 10 nodes and 5 connected components and found that the answer is always 5 so the answer to my question is 100, But how to prove this **formally**?

Comment: We start at graph with $200$ vetrices and no edges, then we add edges one by one to get the forest $G$. Adding each edge will connect $2$ previously unconnected components -- we can't add an edge to a tree (why?). So each edge reduces number of connected components exactly by $1$, so $E+C=200$ thus $E=100$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin You can add edge to a tree that's completely fine, If I have a-b then I can make it a-b-c

Comment: Plus you can't say "then we add edges one by one to get the forest ." because we don't know what  will look like, this isn't formal

Comment: If it's not that formal, you can use induction (In the argument above pretend we know that $G$ that is given, arbitrary. Can we construct it from scratch by adding edges one by one? Why not?). In the a-b a-b-c example above you add a node c also. I meant without adding a node.

Comment: "So each edge reduces number of connected components exactly by 1" not true, again if I have a-b adding a-b-c still the number didn't change...

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin any help with this?

Comment: Very sorry I couldn't make my point that clear without rigorous proof.

Comment: @clark979m If c was not already in the same component with a-b, then adding the edge b-c does indeed reduce the number of components by one. If c was already in the same component with a-b, then you already had a path from c to b before adding the direct edge b-c, and adding that edge makes a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, induction. We prove that for a forest $V=E+C$ where $V$ stand for vertices. $E$ for edges and $C$ for connected components number resp. We do induction for number of edges. Base case with $0$ edges is obvious (each vertice is a connected component itself).

Suppose we have a forest $G$ with $E$ edges. We remove one arbitrary edge. It did belong to a connected component. This component now splits in $2$ -- it can't split into more than $2$ connected components and can't remain connected -- if it is still connected (say we remove the edge between $A$ and $B$, if $A$ and $B$ are still connected) then there was two paths from $A$ to $B$ then there was a cycle. So by removing an edge from a forest we add one connected component, $V=(E-1)+(C+1)$ did hold by induction hypotheses for $E-1$, now it holds for $E$. QED.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a forest with $n$ vertices, $e$ edges and $k$ district connect components. Let $C_1,\dots,C_k$ be the components of $G$. Then each $C_i(1\leq i\leq k)$ is a tree. For $1\leq i\leq k$, let $C_i$ has $n_i$ vertices and $e_i$ edges. Then we have, $e_i+1=n_i$. Hence adding all these we get,$
\sum_{i=1}^ke_i+k=\sum_{i=1}^kn_i
\Rightarrow e+k=n.$

Now according to the problem, here put $n=200$ and $k=100$. From above formula, number of edges is $e=n-k=200-100=100$.